# Django: General query accesible from all views

Tags: django, django-queryset

I am a bit confused concerning a general query. I have a model with a class Customer information and a class with Comment related to these customers.

I want to add in my base.html template an Info tag where I can see the last created comments. So it should be visible in all templates/views.

```
lastCom = Comment.objects.order_by('-id').last()
```

The problem is that I want to define the query once and not for each view separetely.

Do you have a hint how define a query only on one place and to access it in each template and not to define the query in each view?

What to choose Model Managers, ListViews etc.

Comment: Once per customer or once for the whole project?

Comment: Good point - should have clarified that. Once for the whole project. So the last created comments overall independently from the customers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write custom [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors):

```
def last_comment(request):
    return {'lastComm': Comment.objects.order_by('-id').last()}
```

In settings module you should add it to `TEMPLATES` setting:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'path.to.processor.last_comment'
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

This will add `lastComm` variable to each template.

Comment: Thanks. All works fine. One comment: In the processor file you have to import the class comment: `from myapp.models import Comment`